# Can't navigate through a file using fseek (C)

Tags: c, fseek

I'm trying to navigate through a file until I find two rows where the first 4 digits of the first are different from the first 4 of the next one.
For that I've been using fseek to navigate trough it until I find the sequence I want. It's a list of population by decade, and for each decade there is more than one line, but they are all in a sequence, from the oldest to the newest year.
And I use ftell in main to get the first offset so that I can start reading in the middle of the file.

The problem here is that it keeps going backwards even when the offset is positive and it should forwards.

The lines that should make it go forward are this:

```
encontrar_inicio(f, ano, offset/2);
```

And this is what it shows:

```
1980 é maior que 1950 ano maior, anda para a frente
1980 é maior que 1910 ano maior, anda para a frente
1980 é maior que 1900 ano maior, anda para a frente
1980 é maior que 1880 ano maior, anda para a frente
1980 é maior que 1860 ano maior, anda para a frente
```

It says 1980 is bigger than [year], go forward. But it doesn't. And after the printf that gives those line is the line I've posted above.

And this is the whole function:

```
void encontrar_inicio (FILE *f, int ano, long int offset)
{
    int i, meio, ano2;
    char aux[100], aux2[100], aux3[100], lixo[100];

    //printf("%lu\n", offset);
    fseek( f, offset, SEEK_SET);

    fgets(aux, 100, f);

    fgets(aux2, 5, f);

    ano2 = atoi(aux2);

    if(ano==ano2)
    {
        printf("%d é igual a %d anos iguais, anda para trás\n", ano, ano2);
        encontrar_inicio(f, ano, -offset/2);//go back in the file
    }
    if(ano != ano2)
    {   if(ano < ano2)
        {
            printf("%d é menor q %d ano menor, anda para trás\n", ano, ano2);
            encontrar_inicio(f, ano, -offset/2);//go back in the file
        }
        if(ano > ano2)
        {
            printf("aqui\n");
            fgets(lixo, 100, f);//next line
            fgets(aux3, 5, f);
            int ano3 = atoi(aux3);


            if(ano==ano3)
            {
                printf("%d é igual a %d Encontrou o ano, começa a ler\n", ano, ano3);
                return;
                //começa a ler
            }
            if(ano!=ano3)
            {
                printf("%d é maior que %d ano maior, anda para a frente\n", ano, ano3);
                encontrar_inicio(f, ano, offset/2); //go forward in the file

            }

        }
    }
}
```

I've been changing a couple of things but I can't get any further than this. Any help would be appreciated.

I would also to apologise if there is anything wrong with this question as it's my first one.

The file it reads from is like this (with all the decades in the middle):

```
year,age,marst,sex,people
1850,0,0,1,1483789
1850,0,0,2,1450376
1850,5,0,1,1411067
2000,90,4,2,29292
2000,90,5,1,147615
2000,90,5,2,774069
2000,90,6,1,15627
2000,90,6,2,59113
```

EDIT - Ended doing it like this, and it's working like a charm.

```
void encontrar_inicio (FILE *f, int ano, long offsetmin, long offsetmax)
{
    int ano2;
    char aux[100], aux2[200], aux3[100], *aux4, lixo[100], lixo2[100];
    long meio;

    meio = (offsetmin+offsetmax)/2;

    int anoinicio = inicio_ficheiro_ano(f);

    if(ano==anoinicio)
    {
        printf("%d igual a %d, começar a ler", ano, anoinicio);
        //inserir dados em;
        return;
    }

    fseek( f, meio, SEEK_SET);

    fgets(aux, 100, f);

    fgets(aux2, 200, f);

    aux4 = strtok(aux2, ",");

    ano2 = atoi(aux4);

    if(ano==ano2)
    {
        printf("%d é igual a %d anos iguais, anda para trás\n", ano, ano2);
        //return;
        encontrar_inicio(f, ano, offsetmin, meio);//go back in the file
    }
    if(ano != ano2)
    {   if(ano < ano2)
        {
            printf("%d é menor q %d ano menor, anda para trás\n", ano, ano2);
            //return;
            encontrar_inicio(f, ano, offsetmin, meio);//go back in the file
        }
        if(ano > ano2)
        {
            fgets(lixo, 100, f);//next line
            fgets(aux3, 5, f);
            int ano3 = atoi(aux3);

            if(ano==ano3)
            {
                printf("%d é igual a %d Encontrou o ano, começa a ler\n", ano, ano3);
                fseek(f, -strlen(aux2), SEEK_CUR);
                return;
                //começa a ler
            }
            if(ano!=ano3)
            {
                printf("%d é maior que %d ano maior, anda para a frente\n", ano, ano3);
                encontrar_inicio(f, ano, meio, offsetmax); //go forward in the file

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to change the first `encontrar_inicio` with:

```
encontrar_inicio(f, ano, offset/2);
```

(your version is using a negative offset)

And on the second with:

```
encontrar_inicio(f, ano, offset + ((maxOffset - offset)/2));
```

(your version was going back, instead of going forward. offset is greater than offset/2)

Comment: hat won't change anything. It will do exactly the same. 
And I believe the value of offset/2 is the same offset-(offset/2).

But you talked about a negative offset, can't I use it? If so how can I go backwards in my search?

Thanks!

Comment: theare is a differene in odd numbers because you are using int division.
I've updated the answer, check it now.

Comment: I've used what you said but it still doesn't get to the "final" state that should make the file print:

                'printf("%d é igual a %d Encontrou o ano, começa a ler\n", ano, ano3);'

Instead it now has a odd behaviour if its bigger, because of the 'offset + (offset/2)' it "goes out" and it compares the year with '0'.
Can't I just go half offset forward or backwards?

Comment: I see. do you have the max value that a offset can take?

have you updated all the `encontrar_inicio`? There are at least 3.
can you update your post with a exemple of the file to be parsed?

Comment: probably you want to go forward with `offset + ((maxOffset - offset)/2)`

Comment: The max value is twice the first input of the offset. It's generated in another function that determines the file size. And the first offset I user is half of that size. So the max value should be offset*2 using the first one. Or it can be generated with the function  `meio_ficheiro(f)`.

Yes, I have updated all three of them. 

And I've already edited the question with an excerpt of the file.

Comment: I've set a `maxoffset` with `maxoffset = meio_ficheiro(f)*2;` and then changed the last `encontrar_inicio` to `offset + ((maxoffset - offset)/2)` and the others to `offset - ((maxoffset - offset)/2)`. And this is weird. If they both had this the program wouldn't work. But if only the first had it the program would work if the year was 1990. But only with this year. And I'm still trying to figure out to make it go backwards....

Comment: Actulay, backwards is just like you said: `offset/2`. the other way, would never reach offset 0 if needed (offset - (offset/2))

check if the file has an even number of rows because you will not be able to reach last row if the file has an odd number of lines.

Comment: OT: `offset + ((maxOffset - offset)/2)` is equal to `(maxOffset + offset)/2`

Comment: I finally got it! First of all I had to jump the first line, because id dind't had any valuable information. Then I added a function that gave me the first year of the file so that when it was inputed it went there. Because has I had the program it wouldn't work for the first year.
Than I changed the `encontrar_inicio` to `void encontrar_inicio (FILE *f, int ano, long offsetmin, long offsetmax)` this way it was the function that determined where was the middle. And this way it worked recursively. 
Thank you all for the support!
I'll post the "solution" above.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to use `SEEK_CUR` to seek relativly to the current position, but `SEEK_SET` which positions absolutly.

Comment: I also thought about that but ended up keeping with the `SEEK_SET` and giving two values for the offset, a minimum and a maximum. This way it always calculated the value in between as it worked recursively.